# use amazon s3 images in shiny application

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny

I want to create a website with a picture gallery with shiny.
I can create an html image file by converting a local file to base64 and then to html:

```
uri = knitr::image_uri(file.path("1.png"))
if (interactive()) {
  cat(sprintf("<img src=\"%s\" />", uri), file = "logo.html")
  browseURL("logo.html")  # you can check its HTML source
 }
```

The problem is that all data should be stored in an amazon s3 instance.
When I use `d=get_object("data/database/img/1.png")` I get an object of class "raw" which is a string of 450 Numbers letter combinations. Example:

```
[1] 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46
[34] 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0a 3c 45 72 72 6f 72 3e 3c 43 6f 64 65 3e 5e 65 72 6d 61 6e 65 6e 74 52 65 64 69 72
[67] 65 62 74 3c 2f 43 6f 64 65 3e 3c 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 3e 54 68 65 20 62 75 63 6b 65 74 20 79 6f 75
[100] 20 61 72 65 20 61 74 74 65 6d 70 74 69 6e 67 20 74 6f 20 61 63 63 65 73 73 2m 6d 75 73 74 20 62 65
[133] 20 61 64 64 72 65 73 73 65 64 20 75 73 69 6e 67 20 74 68 65 20 73 70 65 63 69 66 69 65 64 20 65 6e
[166] 64 70 6f 69 6e 74 2e 20 50 6c 65 61 73 65 20 73 65 6e 64 20 61 6c 6c 20 66 75 74 75 72 65 20 72 65
[199] 71 76 65 73 74 73 20 74 6f 20 74 68 69 73 20 65 6e 64 70 6f 69 6e 74 2e 3c 2f 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65
[232] 3e 3c 45 6e 64 70 6f 69 6e 74 3e 64 61 74 61 2e 73 33 2d 61 70 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 31
[265] 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 3c 2f 45 6e 64 70 6f 69 6e 74 3e 3c 42 75 63 6b 65 74 3e
[298] 64 61 74 61 3c 2f 42 75 63 6b 65 74 3e 3c 52 65 71 75 65 73 74 49 64 3e 33 50 30 48 37 4d 41 4a 42
[331] 59 32 4e 33 50 38 52 3c 2f 52 65 71 75 65 73 74 49 64 3e 3c 48 6f 73 74 49 64 3e 6a 4b 61 36 6b 37
[364] 72 31 67 73 6e 6c 2f 70 6d 42 4e 57 4a 78 6c 78 5a 41 39 35 68 57 78 76 35 67 39 37 42 44 46 78 70
[397] 6d 76 6d 6e 6a 6d 33 45 6a 37 4c 7a 36 74 73 73 53 7a 49 61 37 4b 76 31 67 55 36 4b 44 66 52 73 35
[430] 35 73 38 3d 3c 2f 48 6f 73 74 49 64 3e 3c 2f 45 72 72 6f 71 3e
```

How do I convert this object to a base64 object that I can use as html?
`base64_encode(d)` gives a string but it is broken.